# Unable to INSERT any records in MYSQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to develop an app and I need an API, so I am trying now PHP in order to pass my variables from the app to the MYSQL. I am trying with $_GET first in order to see if everything works fine. I tried to pass variables to the database through MYSQL Workbench and then from the app and worked fine. But, when I emptied the table and tried again it didn't work! So I am guessing that my loop doesn't respond well to the fact that my table is empty(?)

This is the code that checks for the email and username if exists and if not insert the variables:

```
$result = 'notSet';


$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
     if(strcmp($row['email'],$email)==0){ //strcmp uses two strings and it returns an integer, if 0 then no differences if more than 0 then there are
        $result = 'Email exists';
    }else{
        if(strcmp($row['username'],$username)==0){
        $result = 'Username exists';
    }else{          
        //encryption
        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project VALUES ('$userid', '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')");
        $result = 'Registered';
        session_start();
        $session = session_id();
        $SESSION['username']=$username;
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas??

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project VALUES ('$userid', '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')") or die(mysql_error()); try mysql_error() to know the error

Comment: $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project VALUES ('$userid', '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')"); here you are literally inserting "$user_id" into the DB. try removing the ' '. Though you should try using PDO

Comment: after  VALUES ('$userid', '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')"); the order is correct like in database table

Comment: @DhanushBala I already try that it doesn't reach there.

Comment: @Shai thank you very much for the tutorials, I will give it a try.

Comment: or die(mysql_error()) , any error

Comment: Check wether the age or year is integer in database. If it is then you should not be using single quotes for the same in the SQL query

Comment: @BenisonSam So double quotes, for the integers variables?

Comment: integers variables do not need quotes.

Comment: No just remove the quotes. No quotes are required for integer datatype. But keep the quotes for varchar, text, date or any such datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is empty. $query is returning false. Because of this your loop is not executed. You should change the code like this:

```
if($query){
    while(){
       //check username and email 
    }
}
else{
     // execute insert query
}
```

Can you try this code:

```
$result = 'notSet';

$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE email = '$email' OR username = '$username' ");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) === 0 ){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project VALUES ('$userid', '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')");
    $result = 'Registered';
    session_start();
    $session = session_id();
    $SESSION['username']=$username;
}
else{
    $result = 'Username or Email exists';
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, I tried your way but it didn't work though it seems correct.

Comment: You're close, but it's not right. Even with an empty resultset, mysql_query() will return a resource. A resource evaluates ever to `true`. It should be followed by `if (mysql_num_rows($query) === 0)` and your logic.

Comment: @VMai can you post your answer please so I can see what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

We should add single quotes `'` only if field type is not integer type. For eg if `userid` field is integer type and rest of fields are not integer type then query will be

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO project VALUES ($userid, '$fullname','$username','$password','$course','$year','$age','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First: you should switch to PDO or mysqli, because the mysql_* functions are deprecated. Please follow the links in Shais comment.

To get the `INSERT` done, you've got to change your logic. With your code right now, it will never be executed for an empty resultset. You could do it so:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project");

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
    // we've got results, let's loop through the resultset
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        // do something with the result
    }
}
else {
    // we've got no results, 
    // do the insert
}
```

[mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) will return a resource for `SELECT` type queries. A resource evaluates in PHP to `true`. You can use mysql_num_rows() to check, whether your resultset is not empty.

Excerpt from the linked manual:

> Use mysql_num_rows() to find out how many rows were returned for a
>   SELECT statement

PS: Please consider the content of the red box.

Comment: Yes now I understand what I was doing. I will try that also, but now I will start looking into PDO and mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO project set id=$userid,
                                               'fullname'=$fullname,
                                               'username'=$username,
                                               'password'=$password,
                                               'course'=$course,
                                               'year'=$year,
                                               'age'=$age,
                                               'email'=$email
                        ");
?>
```